# Typography String does not stay withing bounds of Material-UI CardContent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, typography

I have the following `CardContent` in my React Material-UI

```
<CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
  <Typography component="p" className={classes.title} variant="title">
    {this.props.post.title}
  </Typography>
    {this.props.post.photo &&
      (<div className={classes.photo}>
        <img
          className={classes.media}
            src={'/api/posts/photo/'+this.props.post._id}
            />
  </div>)}
  <pre>
    <Typography component="p" className={classes.text}>
      {this.props.post.text}
    </Typography>
  </pre>
</CardContent>
```

My problem is that if I have long string in `{this.props.post.text}` the text does not wrap to stay within the bounds of the card. Instead it gets truncated at the edge of the card.

How can I get this to wrap instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `<pre>` maitains the initial formatting of the string, so if it was one long line, it will remain that way when it is rendered. In this case the line was longer than the width of the card.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not use `<pre>`I did go around with **whiteSpace:'pre-wrap'**

```
<Typography  variant="body1" component="div" style={{whiteSpace:'pre-wrap'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(this.state.formData.About)} />
```